# Find the average of a value in a list of tuples within a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure why the following code isn't looping through the entire list and summing all of the targeted values. It's only looping through the first item within my list.

```
def average_grade(students):
    sum = 0
    grades_num = 0
    for s in students:
        for assignment_name, grade in s['assignments']:
            sum += grade
            grades_num += 1
        average = sum / grades_num
        return average
average_grade(students)
```

I can print all of the grades for my entire list, but when I attempt to sum the grade it will stop at the first dictionary.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your data, we can only guess. Please provide a MVCE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement is *in* the loop so at the end of the first iteration the function returns. Just un-indent the `average` calculation and the `return` statement.

```
def average_grade(students):
    sum = 0
    grades_num = 0
    for s in students:
        for assignment_name, grade in s['assignments']:
            sum += grade
            grades_num += 1
    average = sum / grades_num
    return average

average_grade(students)
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks so much!